# Time Complexity of searching

Tags: algorithm, sorting

there is a sorted array which is of very large size. every element is repeated more than once except one element. how much time will it take to find that element?
Options are:
1.O(1)
2.O(n)
3.O(logn)
4.O(nlogn)

Comment: Well, what do you think and why?

Comment: I think it should be O(logn)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what do you think?

Comment: Using "Binary Search". O(log(n))

Comment: It is O(n) since you cannot use the sorted property to locate the item faster than inspecting each item in turn.

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural but the answer is given as O(n)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: All elements before the non repeated one have first occurrence at even index (2n, n = 0,1,..) and next occurrence at odd index (2n + 1, n=0,1,..). and vice versa for after non repeated element. You can use these property I think as a binary search criteria

Comment: @CherkesgillerTural, "more than once", not twice

Comment: Ohh sorry ,I have misunderstood.

Comment: Is every element repeated the same number of times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question is O(n) and here's why.

Let's first summarize the knowledge we're given:

- A large array containing elements
- The array is sorted
- Every item except for one occurs more than once

Question is what is the time growth of searching for that one item that only occurs once?

The sorted property of the array, can we use this to speed up the search for the item? Yes, and no.

First of all, since the array isn't sorted by the property we must use to look for the item (only one occurrence) then we cannot use the sorted property in this regard. This means that optimized search algorithms, such as binary search, is out.

However, we know that if the array is sorted, then all items that have the same value will be grouped together. This means that when we look at an item we see for the first time we only have to compare it to the following item. If it's different, we've found the item we're looking for.

"see for the first time" is important, otherwise we would pick the first value since there will be a boundary between two groups of items where the two items are different.

So we have to move from one end of the array to the other, and compare each item to the following item, and this is an O(n) operation.

Basically, since the array isn't sorted by the property we're looking at, we're back to a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

Must be O(n).

- The fact that it's sorted doesn't help. Suppose you tried a binary method, jumping into the middle somewhere. You see that the value there has a neighbour that is the same. Now which half do you go to?
- How would you write a program to find the value? You'd start at one end an check for an element whose neighbour is not the same. You'd have to walk the whole array until you found the value. So O(n)